# interpretation of properties of R-linear maps as algebra maps between symmetric algebra and target

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{mS}{\textbf S}$
Say we have a (commutative) ring $R$ and $M$ a *free* $R$-module.

Then $R$-**linear** maps from $M$ to an $R$-**algebra** $N$ factor as $M\to\mS(M)\to N$, where $\mS(M)$ is the symmetric algebra, $M\to\mS(M)$ is the canonical map and $\mS(M)\to N$ is an **algebra** map. So far so good.

**smaller question 1** (vague): is this the only (good?) way to transform a linear map into a ring map?

If $M$ is free of rank $n$ over $R$, then it's known that $\mS(M)$ can be viewed as $R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$. 
**smaller question 2:** can such identification be done *without* choosing a basis?

Assume now $M$ itself is an $R$-algebra (still free), and let's rename it to $B$. Then multiplication $l_b:B\to B$ by any $b\in B$ is $R$-linear, hence induces $R$-algebra maps, call them $\alpha_b:\mS(B)\to B$.

**Main question:** Are there good ways to interpret properties of the linear map $l_b$ in terms of properties of the ring homomorphism $\alpha_b$? For example, the characteristic polynomial (which is in $R[T]$), or maybe the norm ($=$ free coefficient of the characteristic polynomial)?

I would like, as much as possible, to avoid using a basis. Partly because I am actually interested in *projective* $R$, partly because I am actually interested in the geometric picture ($\text{Spec} B\to\text{Spec} R$, potentially involving $\text{Spec}(\mS(B))$) and it seems that (one) way to "geometrize" a linear map is by viewing it as a morphism $\text{Spec} B\to\text{Spec}{\mS(B)}$.

Comment: Ans. to q1: No, but it does have a desirable universal property (universal among maps to a *commutative* algebra). There are also noncommutative versions (exterior algebra). A construction which (apparently, I have no intuition for it atm) also gives a construction of "polynomials on the module M", is the divided power algebra.

Ans to q2: No. Choosing the isomorphism is choosing a basis. The elements $T_i$ are the cooridinate functions on the module $M$.

Comment: [This paper](https://eudml.org/doc/81793) is what I was thinking about writing the first response.

I don't know how to think of the morphism $\alpha_b$ geometrically. For example, it could be the inclusion of a point (e.g. if $B$ is a finite field extension of $R$ a field), or it could be the inclusion of $n$ points (e.g. if $B=R^{\oplus n}$ as a ring).

Comment: Actually, I think I've got part of it. The simple case when $R$ is a field, and $B=R[x]/f$ for an irreducible polynomial $f$, and $b=x$. Choosing a basis $\{1,x,...,x^{\deg f-1}\}$ for $B$, the map $S(B)\rightarrow B$ has kernel generated by (well things like $u-u\otimes 1$) and you can work it out so that the kernel is generated by these only as $u$ runs over the basis elements for $B$ and, if $f=x^n+\cdots + c_0$ then also $f=x^{\otimes n}+\cdots + c_0$. So on spectra we get $\text{Spec}(B)\rightarrow \mathbf{A}_R^1$ corresponding to the map $R[x]\rightarrow R[x]/f$.